# npm config not being updated inside the same npm script

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, npm, terminal

Let's say I have this npm script:

```
"test": "npm config set email test@test.com && npm config get email"
```

After running `npm run test` I don't see email updated.

Similarly if create bash script like so:

```
npm config set email test@test.com
npm config get email
```

and add it to npm script, it still works the same way.

This might be a bash issue, I'm a very new to bash.
Is there a way to make it work - meaning to set the config values and use them in the script?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is a bit more complicated. Consider this:

```
c:\cygwin64\home\qbolec\baro>npm config set email old@email.com

c:\cygwin64\home\qbolec\baro>npm run test

> baro@1.0.0 test c:\cygwin64\home\qbolec\baro
> echo 'before'&& grep '^email' /cygdrive/c/Users/qbolec/.npmrc&& npm config set email test@test.com&& echo 'after'&& grep '^email' /cygdrive/c/Users/qbolec/.npmrc&& echo 'get'&& npm config get email

'before'
init.author.email=qbolec@gmail.com
email=old@email.com
'after'
init.author.email=qbolec@gmail.com
email=test@test.com
'get'
old@email.com

c:\cygwin64\home\qbolec\baro>npm config get email
test@test.com

c:\cygwin64\home\qbolec\baro>cat package.json
{
  "name": "baro",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo 'before'&& grep '^email' /cygdrive/c/Users/qbolec/.npmrc&& npm config set email test@test.com&& echo 'after'&& grep '^email' /cygdrive/c/Users/qbolec/.npmrc&& echo 'get'&& npm config get email"

  },
  "author": "Jakub Łopuszański <qbolec@gmail.com>",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

It looks like the .npmrc file is actually changed by the `npm config set` immediately, and the change is permanent, but not available for reading through `npm config get`. However, I don't know how to overcome this.